# eWAY payment processor not sending receipts on membership signup

Tags: payment-processor, contribution-page, receipts, eway

When signing up for membership using contribution page, our eWAY payment processor is not generating a receipt for the end user. The Civi contact is created correctly, the Civi receipt is sent to the end user and the transaction is processed correctly through eWAY but eWAY receipt is not being sent.
If a membership is added to an existing Civi contact, the process works correctly, that is, membership created, Civi receipt sent and eWAY receipt sent.
We have been advised by eWAY that no email address is being submitted for these transactions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried both the core eWAY payment processor and the [eWAY Recurring](https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor) extension?

Comment: how was this issue fixed ? @Ten4PL